# Added html via js and now scroll bar does not appear when overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create html code with javascript, but I dont know why when I the code overflows the browser page, the scroll bar does not appear , neither I can scroll with the middle wheel, what can I do to tell the browser I don't see this?
I have seen some questions about this but everyone error was that the put in  css overflow: hidden;. But that's not my case, is there something wrong about my css or js?

```
<script>
        document.getElementById("addGrup").addEventListener("click", addGrup, false);
        document.getElementsByClassName("grup").addEventListener("click", deleteGrup, false);
        function deleteGrup() {
            event.target.parentElement.remove()
        }
        function addGrup() {
            var element = document.getElementById("allgrup");
            var numberOfChildren = Number(document.getElementsByTagName('div').length)
            if (numberOfChildren == null)
                numberOfChildren = 0;
    
            let il = document.createElement('il');
            il.className = 'grup';
            il.id = 'grup' + numberOfChildren;
    
            let inputLlista = document.createElement('input');
            inputLlista.type = 'text'
            il.appendChild(inputLlista)
    
            let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
            deleteButton.id = 'deleteGrup';
            deleteButton.textContent = 'x';
            il.appendChild(deleteButton);
    
            let labelLlista = document.createElement('label');
            labelLlista.textContent="heoiahñskldjnskljdn askldjn aslkjdnlaksjnd"
            il.appendChild(labelLlista)
    
    
            deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteGrup, false);
            document.getElementById("allGrup").appendChild(il);
        }
    </script>



body {
    background-color: grey;
}

ul {
    position: fixed;
}

il {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 220;
    margin: 20;
}

label {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

#deleteGrup {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 1;
}

#addGrup {
    padding: 16px 32px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    left: 90%;
    position: absolute;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}


button:hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: have you tried explicitly setting overflow to auto or scroll?

Comment: @DennisHackethal auto does nothing, and scroll shows the scrollbars still does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Delete all css of `ul` and change `#addGrup` button to:

```css
top: 0;
right: 0;
position: fixed;
```